# Why "surv.svm" shows error in "mlr3proba" package of R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, mlr3

I am using `mlr3proba` package of `R` for machine learning survival analysis.
My dataset contains factor, numeric and integer features.
To implement `SVM` I wrote the code below:

```
task <- TaskSurv$new(id = "id", backend = dataset, time = time, event = status)

train <- sample(task$nrow, 0.8 * task$nrow)
test <- setdiff(seq_len(task$nrow), train)

resampling <- rsmp("cv", folds = 10)

learner <- lrn("surv.svm", gamma.mu ="0.1")

learner$train(task, row_ids = train)
```

But when I run the last line of code, It shows the error below:

```
Error in -ub: invalid argument to unary operator
```

When I run `SVM` in main `survivalsvm` package, it works, but in `mlr3proba` does not work.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't work (I think you mean `TaskSurv$new` instead of `TaskSurv`). Please also post the data.

Comment: It was a mistake here, but I have written "TaskSurv$new" in my original code. My problem is last line.

Comment: This still isn't a reprex, can you provide [reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes calls to `library`, the version of the packages you are using and a dataset that we can use, or use one of the ones available in mlr3proba.